# decoding binary to mips instruction using mips language

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly

Hi when decoding mips using mips language you have to partition the code.

After youve partitioned the instruction lets say a branch instruction into:

```
OP code
Sregister
Tregister 
Address
```

`$t1` contains the value `0100` which is 8 and I wanted to print this as 8:

If i tried to print `$t1` i get the integer `0100` instead of `8`. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: _"If i tried to print $t1 i get the integer 0100 instead of 8"_ How exactly did you try to print it?

Comment: li $v0, 4  then li $a0, $t1 then syscall

Comment: @user3175173 What? Firstly you can't use `li` with a register instead of an immediate. Secondly, are you using spim or MARS? Because if you are syscall  4 is print string.

Comment: sorry i meant: li $v0 1 then add $a0, $t1, $zero then syscall. Its still printing 0100 instead of the actual int

Comment: and ive been using spim